# how can I show that the sequence $x_{n}=\frac{n}{n^{2}+1}+\frac{n}{n^2+2}+...+\frac{n}{n^2+n},n=1,2,...$ converges?

Tags: analysis

How can I check if the sequence $x_{n}=\frac{n}{n^{2}+1}+\frac{n}{n^2+2}+...+\frac{n}{n^2+n},n=1,2,...$ converges?Is there a theorem that I could use?

Answer (score 6):

We have $1>x_n>\frac{n^2}{n^2+n}$ Now apply the squeeze theorem.

Comment: Have you found this,using this relation:
$$\frac{n}{n^2+n}+...+\frac{n}{n^2+1}<x_{n}<\frac{n}{n^2+1}+...+\frac{n}{n^2+1} \Rightarrow \frac{n^2}{n^2+n}<x_{n}<\frac{n^2}{n^2+1}$$

Comment: Yes, I used almost exactly the same relation.

Comment: Great!!!Thanks a lot for your answer!!!

Answer (score 4):

Notice the following:
Every two integers $n,k$ such that $1\leq k \leq n$  satisfy 
$$\frac {1}{n+1} = \frac{n}{n^2+n} \leq \frac{n}{n^2+k} \leq \frac{n}{n^2}=\frac{1}{n}$$
So we get 
$$ \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}} = n \cdot \frac {1}{n+1} \leq x_n \leq n \cdot \frac{1}{n} =1$$
Thus by the [Sandwich Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) we get $x_n\rightarrow 1$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{n}{n^2}+\ldots+\frac{n}{n^2+n}<x_n<\frac{n}{n^2}+\ldots+\frac{n}{n^2}\implies \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n}{n}<\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n<\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n+1}$$
We can re-write it as,
$$1<\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n<1$$
So, $x_n=1$

Comment: I understand..Could I also take this relation: $\frac{n}{n^2+n}+...+\frac{n}{n^2+1}<x_{n}<\frac{n}{n^2+1}+...+\frac{n}{n^2+1} \Rightarrow \frac{n^2}{n^2+n}<x_{n}<\frac{n^2}{n^2+1}$ ?

Comment: @evinda Certainly you could use that, the point is to get an inequality from which we can have the left inequality to be equal to the right inequality.

Comment: @evinda I think you meant $\frac{n}{n^2+n}$ instead of $\frac{n}{n^2+1}$ on your left inequality.

Comment: Oh yes right!!!I accidentally wrote $n^2+1$,I meant $n^2+n$!!!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!!!

Comment: Yes, I thought so...it is a typo

Comment: You are most welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Use Riemann Sums so the sequence should converge to an integral.

Comment: Have you given any thought towards which integral this would be a Riemann sum for?

Comment: no, but I can see that by sandwich you can solve it.
if you insist I can calculate it for you in the near time
I just have no time now.
you can start calculating it by getting out $\frac{1}{n}$